# Help with Font identification

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Kindly help with identifying the following fonts, I've tried all online font identifying service without any luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Formal Script Font](http://allfont.net/download/formal-script-421-bt/) via allfont.net

[image: Formal Script]

Comment: Thanks, It was perfect. If you don't mind can you please let me know how did you identify ?

Comment: @TunaMachhli I have this font